# Applications with Phone gap

Tags: cordova

Is phonegap a good tool to develop mobile applications if you just want to upload images from the cameras phone and use the build in GPS?

Do I need Mac OS to develop api for I-Phone? Can I develop api for i-phone using phonegap on MS Windows environment?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop an application with phonegap for iOs you should have a mac to compile your app. You could use the phonegap build beta to do your building but this would not be a smooth development workflow.

The camera API and the GPS API work fine for my applications on ios, regarding phonegap there should not be any basic issues.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is good if you plan to build a generic your app onto multiple platforms (android, IOS, Windows etc). It will save you production time. However if you plan to use native features like the ios camera etc then then you will need to create an individual app for each platform.